# Insert numbers and symbols after certain string

Tags: bash, sed

My file is the following
cat inputfile

```
mat 523 

mat 22
```

I want to insert the following after the mat's line

```
3006.03c 1.86607E-07    % Li-6
3007.03c 2.30149E-06    % Li-7
5010.03c 3.17890E-07    % B-10
5011.03c 1.27955E-06    % B-11
6000.03c 2.02446E-04    % C-nat
```

I did the following:

```
sed -e '/mat/a
3006.03c 1.86607E-07    % Li-6
3007.03c 2.30149E-06    % Li-7
5010.03c 3.17890E-07    % B-10
5011.03c 1.27955E-06    % B-11
6000.03c 2.02446E-04    % C-nat
' inputfile > outputfile
```

But there is something error in the symbols etc. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's expected output?

Comment: @Mohd, good that you have showed your efforts, always try to show sample input, sample output and your efforts in all your posts.

Comment: btw your `sed` command needs a ``\`` before each of the newline to make it work. However `r` command would be better if you store your multiline input string in a file.

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved my issue :)